# Stacked content, order wrong with hidden overflow

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

Edited to show current code and add html: 
I'm still learning CSS and I have a bit of a problem. I have a header image on top of a page. Overlaying the image I have a header bar with a home-button.

```
#header {height:170px; background-color:#f5fdfb; display:block; overflow:hidden; position:relative;}

#header_bild {
padding-top:0px;
height:170px;
z-index:5;
}

#header_bar {
background-image:url(header_bar.png);
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:151px;
height:31px;
z-index:10
}
```

But I want people in the CMS to be able to upload a header image that is too large and it will be automatically cropped. I thought I could do this by adding overflow:hidden to the header tag. And it works. But as soon as I add overflow:hidden, the header bar is suddenly behind the header image, instead of on top of it where it belongs. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The stuff in the CMS wasn't actually coded by me. I'm only editing the CSS files. So I can only show you the html that I can see when viewing the source file of the site:

```
<body>
<div id="siteborder">
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<div id="header_bar">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="header_img"> 
<img src="./files/header_seed.jpg" border="0"  title="" alt=""></div>

 </div>  
<div id="logo"><a href="http://www.thispage.net"><img src="files/dummy.gif" width="151" height="30"></a></div>

<div id="linie_header"><img src="files/line_header.png" width="992" height="2"></div>
</div><!-- header end -->
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML sample too?

Comment: Could you please add the HTML part or create a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `z-index` in your CSS to specify explicitly what should be "on top" and what should be "behind". There is [plenty](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) of good information out there. `z-index` puts objects with higher value "on top" of objects with lower values. The default if left unspecified is `auto`, which means it takes this value from its parent, which is (usually) 0. The `<html>` tag defaults to a `z-index` of 0, so it follows that nested defaults will also be 0.

```
.thingone { z-index:10;}
.thingtwo { z-index:5;}
.thingthree { }
```

In this example, `<div class="thingone"></div>` will be "on top of" both of the others, and `<div class="thingthree"></div>` will be "underneath" the others, since it is unspecified and therefore defaults to `auto` (the `z-index` of a parent if nested, usually 0). So you should add `z-index:10` (for example) to the particular object you want to be on top (if the image you want "on top" is actually defined by `header_img`):

```
#header_img {
  padding-top:0px;
  height:170px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
}
#header_bar {
  background-image:url(header_bar.png);
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:151px;
  height:31px;
  z-index:20;
}
```

As mentioned by Hilgaran in the comment below, you need to explicitly state a `position` rule for the object you're trying to `z-index`. The default `position` is `relative` for objects not nested underneath parents with alternate `position`s, so specify it explicitly to make `z-index` function.

Comment: Just keep in mind that a position attribute of 'relative', 'absolute', or 'fixed' needs to accompany a z-index.

Comment: Thanks. I have added z-index now, but unfortunatel nothing changes. I want header_bar to be on top and header_img to be be below it. The fault lies in me adding overflow:hidden to the header tag. But I don't know why.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a fiddle containing all relevant code? We need both your HTML and CSS to be able to help you, but please don't paste everything in your files, or it just makes it harder to look through.